# Missing factorial in power series of analytic function

Tags: real-analysis

**Question**:

Let $r \ge 0$ be real numbers. We know from geometric series that $\frac{r}{r-x} = \sum^\infty_{n=0} x^n r^{-n}$ for all $x \in (-r, r)$. Conclude the identity

$$\frac{r}{(r - x) ^ {m + 1}} = \sum^\infty_{n=m} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} x^{n-m} r^{-n}$$

for all integers $m \ge 0$ and $x \in (-r, r)$.

**My attempt is as follows**:

If $f(x) := c(x - a)^n$ then $f^{(k)}(x) = c\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(x - a)^{n-k}$ when $k \le n$ and is zero otherwise. This is easily proven by induction.

Furthermore, power series converge uniformly on **compact** subsets and commute with drivatives. Therefore, they are infinitely differentiable. Then we have

$$(\frac{r}{r-x})^{(m)} = \frac{r}{(r-x)^{m+1}} = (\sum^\infty_{n=0} x^n r^{-n})^{(m)} = \sum^\infty_{n=m} \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}r^{-n}x^{n-m} + \sum^{m-1}_{n=0} 0 = \sum^\infty_{n=m} \frac{n!}{(n-m)!} x^{n-m} r^{-n}$$

for all $x \in [-q, q]$ where $0 < q < r$. For each $x \in (-r, r)$, set $q = |x| + (r - |x|)/2$ and we obtain the conclusion.

The $m!$ is missing from the question. Where was I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\frac r {r-x})^{(m)}=\frac {m!r} {(r-x)^{m+1}}$ and not $\frac {r} {(r-x)^{m+1}}$. Dividing by $m!$ gives the correct identity.